# React Router path '/' alway goes to /doc

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Edit: I added a codesandbox.  It doesn't seem to have the same problem there.  So now I am even more confused.
[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-lamarr-66ygwf?file=/src/components/AuthRoute.js)

I have a very simple mockup to test a concept in the V6 React Router.  When I go to '/' (localhost:3000/) it redirects to /doc automatically.  I have no '/doc' path.  I also get the warning: "No routes matched location "/doc/" which makes sense because I don't have that path. Did I miss something in v6?

Here is App.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthLogin from './components/AuthLayout'
import AuthRoute from './components/AuthRoute'
import Login from './components/Login'

function App() {
  const state = {
    isAuth: true,
    name: 'state'
  }
  const client = 'Andrew'

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path='/'
        element={
          <AuthRoute props={state} >
            <AuthLogin client={client} />
          </AuthRoute>
        }
      />
      <Route path='login' element={<Login props={state} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the contents of Login.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = ({ props }) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <h1>Is Authorized: {props.isAuth.toString()}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Here is the contents of AuthLayout.js:

```
import React from 'react'

const AuthLayout = ({ client }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Auth Layout</h1>
      <h1>{client}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AuthLayout
```

here is the contents of AuthRoute.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Error from './Error'

const AuthRoute = ({ props, client, children }) => {
  if (!props.isAuth) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' replace />
  }
  return children
}

export default AuthRouteimport React from 'react'
```

This really is all there is, it's just a quick mockup and 'doc' as a literally doesn't exist

[image: Results of searching for "doc"]

[image: Project Tree]

Comment: Hi Bryant, please try to provide a minimal reproducible example when you post a question on Stack Overflow. There are three components in your example which we cannot see the contents of.

Comment: *Somewhere* you have some code that is navigating to a `"/doc"` route that you are not rendering a route for. Have you searched your project for any `"doc"` string literal? Is there more code to your app? Is this *really* the [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the post to show that there isn't anything else.

Comment: I don't exactly see this code as a reproducible example. I don't see any overt issues with it. How are you running/serving the app?

Comment: @DrewReese by 'npm run start'.

I don't see any issues with the code either, that's why I came here haha

Comment: Can you see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live? I highly suspect it'll be unreproducible in the sandbox, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @DrewReese I added a codesandbox.  As you predicted it's not an issue there so now I'm just even more confused.

Comment: It certainly seems odd. Try killing all running processes, watchers, etc... maybe even fully exit the terminal, then reopen and restart the app to see if this is still persists.